# Creating Panorama Control Screenshots

Tags: windows-phone, screenshot, panorama-control

The [Microsoft panorama control](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/post/31-Days-of-Windows-Phone-7c-Day-16-The-Panorama-Control.aspx) is a common method for performing layout and navigation in Windows Phone 7 applications. In many blogs and reviews you will find screenshots that show the entire [panorama control in one image](http://www.fanboy.com/2010/02/windows-phone-7.html) instead of individual sections. Is there any way to create these automatically from the XAML code or do you just have to merge the individual pictures using image editing software?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a pretty good workaround. Include explanation, links, screen shots, and working sample app.

[WP7 Tip #002: How do you create Windows Phone 7 panorama application screen shots?](http://www.cjcraft.com/blog/2011/01/19/WP7Tip002HowDoYouCreateWindowsPhone7PanoramaApplicationScreenshots.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

I concur with Matt and Jeff re: what you can accomplish using an external screen shot tool.

You could look into applying an in app screen shot mechanism to the entire panorama. I haven't tested this to see if it would work, but feel free to give it a shot.

[Mark Arteaga - Screen Capture on Windows Phone 7](http://blog.markarteaga.com/ScreenCaptureOnWindowsPhone7.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to automatically create these.

You'll have to merge the individual screenshots together as appropriate.